# Buttons won't work in flash actionscript 3.0 TypeError #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I'm building a simple calculator but when I click the buttons containing the numbers it won't display on the dynamic textbox I putted. I've checked my instance name re-check the codes they're all fine and I seem to get the error `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at game/frame1()`

```
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    one_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayText);
    two_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayText);
    three_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayText);

function displayText(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(event.target.name);

    if(event.target.name == "one_btn"){
        txtAnswer.appendText("1");
    }

    if(event.target.name == "two_btn"){
        txtAnswer.appendText("2");
    }

    if(event.target.name == "three_btn"){
        txtAnswer.appendText("3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put you code ?

Comment: I tested your code and It worked fine. Try to comment `txtAnswer.appendText` lines and retry, If there is no error, verify your text field.

Comment: @akmozo tried it on a different flash file works fine but on my original file, it won't work

Comment: Could you upload your original file somewhere and give us the link to see it?

Comment: Most likely your text field (`txtAnswer`) is either spelled wrong, or not available on the frame where this code runs.    Are you certain the text field is on the timeline on the same frame as this code?